# How to convert dropdown selection from a string to a boolean

Tags: php, html

Trying to convert dropdown selection to a boolean value. I have searched on here and tried multiple things. Nothing is working. Can someone assist in best practice? Here's two examples of what I have tried thus far.

**UPDATE**: Correction made in response to correct answer, below: "You have TWO names on the select as well." Once I eliminated the second name everything functions properly.

HTML:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="paypalvalue">
    <table>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="ODS Categories">ODS                     
    Categories</td></tr><tr><td>
    <select required name="os0" name ="catSelect" id="catSelect" onchange="" 
    class="form-control"><option value="">Select One:</option>
    <option value="M" name="mcategory" id="mcategory" onclick="" />M : 
    </option>
    <option value="P" name="pcategory" id="pcategory" onclick="" />P : 
    </option>
    <option value="E" name="ecategory" id="ecategory" onclick="" />E :     
    </option>
    <option value="C" name="ccategory" id="ccategory" onclick="" />C : 
    </option>
    <option value="O " name="ocategory" id="ocategory"  onclick="" />O : 
    </option>
    </select> </td></tr>
    </table><small>(OPTIONAL: Fill out <i>YOUR</i> user name for selected 
    platform, below.)</small>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
```

Here is java/jquery I have tried: (nothing goes into database)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#catSelect').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'M')
      {
      $("#mcategory").val() == '1';
      $("#pcategory").val() == '0';
      $("#ecategory").val() == '0';
      $("#ccategory").val() == '0';
      $("#ocategory").val() == '0';
      }
    else
    {
        $("#matchcategory").val() = 0;
      }
      });
    });
    //and so on for each
```

Here's the php I have tried:(everything goes into database as 0 regardless of what is selected)
**UPDATE**:I had posted wrong code not used in original question. This is updated to actual code used, and it functions properly.

```
        if ($catSelect == 'M') {
        $mcategory = "1";
    }
    else {
        $mcategory = "0";
    }
    if ($catSelect == 'P') {
        $pcategory = "1";
    }
    else {
        $pcategory = "0";
    }
    if ($catSelect == 'E') {
        $ecategory = "1";
    }
    else {
        $ecategory = "0";
    }
    if ($catSelect == 'C') {
        $ccategory = "1";
    }
    else {
        $ccategory = "0";
    }
    if ($catSelect == 'O') {
        $ocategory = "1";
    }
    else {
        $ocategory = "0";
    }
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. Also, if you could provide details as I am still new to programming. What am I doing wrong? Thank you, in advance, for any assistance!

Comment: Do you get some error? What does it mean $_POST["mcategory".selected]?

Comment: I see no Java here. Am I missing something?

Comment: I changed your JAVA to JavaScript since there is no JAVA here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JavaScript is not JAVA**

---

I do not do much PHP but this construct seems like wishful thinking

```
$_POST["mcategory".selected]
```

I would not expect that but instead

```
$cs = $_POST["catSelect"];
$mcategory = $cs == "M"; // boolean - same as $mcategory = $cs == "M" ? 1 : 0;
```

for example

---

Also options do not have names nor IDs nor event handlers like onclick and you close the start option tag too early

---

You have TWO names on the select as well

---

This is not valid jQuery

```
$("#mcategory").val() == '1';
```

however

```
$("#catSelect").val("M")
```

would select the first option

---

You want something like this:

```html
<select required name="catSelect" id="catSelect" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select One:</option>
    <option value="M">M :  </option>
    <option value="P">P : </option>
    <option value="E">E : </option>
    <option value="C">C : </option>
    <option value="O">O : </option>
</select>
```

using something like

```
$catSelect = strtolower ($_POST["catSelect"]); // get the selected option value
foreach (str_split("mpeco") as $char) { // available options
  ${$catSelect."category"} = $char==$catSelect; // set each variable except selected to false
}
```

Comment: I am going to mark this as the correct answer for the following reasons: 1. "You have TWO names on the select as well"... You are absolutely correct and great catch! 2. In making that change the php functions properly without any changes needed in the php. Thank you so much!

Comment: So your code `$_POST["mcategory".selected] ` works? But why is it needed? `$mcategory = $cs == "M"; $pcategory = $cs == "P";` would work without any javascript and is shorter

Comment: OMG I am so punchy looking at this for so long! MY BAD no excuse here I put one of the other options that I tried from this site and it didn't feel right. I am updating the ACTUAL php code that I wrote and used.

Comment: See  bottom of update for a nifty loop I think should work